# Which method should I use for store large number of data and read?

Tags: c#, save, primitive-types

My scientific C# code generates a lot of data which I used to create output for determined frequency and store them. After each run I usually lose all other data. 90% of outputs are never used and output generation is time consuming process.

For having an overview of my data, I explain the type of data.
I have **four** `double` (*2D array, 1000×1000* ) main variables. These variables need to be solved  *80,000,000* times and then stored.

What I need to do:
-> store all these data in a way that can easily save and read.

For example, all data belong to iteration number 2,000,000 can find and read from the saved file and store in the original array for further calculation or graph generation ...
Order is important and data should be saved orderly.

Please advise me methods which are suitable for me then I can start to learn those ways to implement in the code.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797846/best-way-to-save-load-large-amout-of-data-in-a-net-application

Comment: @Corak: can I use txt files for my application? has it the capibilty of searching for special point and then start read from that point ? I couldn't find good source of information about BinaryFormatter.